# Fragment to fragment shared element transition does not animate

Tags: listview, transition, shared-element-transition

Here is the repo with the app (ListView) https://git.nwt.fhstp.ac.at/dm171521/app-shared-element-transiton

And the exact same thing with RecyclerView (I hoped it would help)
https://git.nwt.fhstp.ac.at/dm171521/app-shared-element-transiton/commits/recyclerView-shared-element

Nothing too complicated (just the important points):

1. create an activity -> load fragments into a `viewPager`
2. load items from JSON into the `listView` of the `ProductsFragment`
3. on item click -> create a second fragment
4. add shared element (a TextView) with unique transitionName
5. `setSharedElementEnterTransition` in the current fragment
6. beginTransaction(...)
7. get the unique `transitionName` in the new Fragment and set it to the equivalent TextView transition name in that fragment.
8. `setSharedElementEnterTransition` in the new fragment
9. nothing, the newly created fragment just appears. The textView from the 1st fragment isn't animated and the textView in the 2nd has its value unchanged.

The transitionNames are set programmatically in each Fragment respectively and are unique in both layouts.

If you ask me "have you tried writing this instead of that" i will probably answer yes, because I've tried to copy from a million tutorials and git repositories with no success, the current state of the repo does not represent all million combinations i've tried. So i'm pretty desperate!

Even writing something as simple as "create Activity with Fragment 1 and a TextView -> click on TextView -> create Fragment 2 and add sharedElement(TextView) -> open" also does nothing. I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Copying a whole app from a git repo worked though, but trying to implement in my case didn't work.

Also, the following is enabled

```
windowContentTransitions
```

Fragment 1

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    // We want to animate the title to the new fragment => shared element
    final TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_name_list);
    Fragment detailsFragment = ProductDetails_fragment.newInstance();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("TRANSITION_NAME", title.getTransitionName());
    detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    Log.i("BEFORE", title.getTransitionName());

    // or getActivity().getSuppportFragmentManager()
    FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.replace(R.id.products_layout, detailsFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .addSharedElement(title, title.getTransitionName())
            .commit();
}
```

Fragment 2

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Transition move = TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move);
        setEnterTransition(move);
        setSharedElementReturnTransition(move);
        setSharedElementEnterTransition(move);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_details_layout, container, false);
        TextView detailsTitle = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_title);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String transitionName = bundle.getString("TRANSITION_NAME");

        detailsTitle.setTransitionName(transitionName);
        Log.i("AFTER", detailsTitle.getTransitionName());

        return rootView;
    }
```

Please, if anyone has a few minutes to clone this repo and see what's going on, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Have a same problem. Week of trying wasted and i got frustrated. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I eventually turned to Activities...  I've read somewhere that fragments in pageViewers have a problem with delays, things not being created on time/too late.